# Почему pd.to_datetime переводит дату в другой формат

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Почему дата формата `10.03.2021` после pd.to_datetime() переходит почему-то в формат 2021-10-03, а не 2021-03-10, как можно исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Pandas создавался в США, где по умолчанию дату пишут в формате `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Кроме того, если день  месяца не превышает 12, то, не зная формата, невозможно однозначно определить где день и где месяц.

Воспользуйтесь параметром [pd.to_datetime(..., dayfirst=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
res = pd.to_datetime(["10.03.2021"], dayfirst=True)
```

или же укажите явно формат даты:

```
res = pd.to_datetime(["10.03.2021"], format="%d.%m.%Y")
```

результат:

```
In [72]: res
Out[72]: DatetimeIndex(['2021-03-10'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```